# uniswap solidity contract: swapExactTokensForTokens Failed

Tags: contract-development, uniswap, swaps

[image]

I used `transferFrom` and `approve`, but still got this error:

```
execution reverted: UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT.
```

I read the source code of Uniswap, `in_` may be `0` ?

This problem has been solved, and now there are new error, `execution reverted`,There should be an error during the swap

This is my complete code

```
  function swap3(uint256 amountIn,uint256 amountOutMin,IRouter _router, IERC20[] calldata path, uint256 deadline
    ) external payable returns (bool b)  {
            require(address(path[0]) != address(0) , "path[0] error________");
            require(address(path[1]) != address(0),"path[1] error________");
            require(address(_router) != address(0) ,"_router error________");
            require(amountIn > 0 ,"amountIn must be > 0");
            IERC20 er = IERC20(path[0]);
            address[] memory n_path = new address[](2);
            n_path[0] = address(path[0]);
            n_path[1] = address(path[1]);
            require(er.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn),"transferFrom failed______");
            require(er.approve(address(_irouter), amountIn),"approve failed_______");
            require(er.balanceOf(address(this)) > 0 ," contract no money_______");
            IRouter(_router).swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn,amountOutMin,n_path,msg.sender,deadline);
            return true;
    }
```

I don't know how to solve it now

Answer (score 0):

The error ([link to code](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol#L44)) happens when the starting amount (`in_`) or an intermediate amount is `0`.

So you need to use `in_ > 0` and make sure that `n_path` has enough liquidity to output amounts `> 0`.

Comment: bruh,Thank you very much for your help,This problem has been solved, and now there are new error, [execution reverted],There should be an error during the swap

Comment: You're approving `_irouter` but then calling `_router`. Is it a typo?